# d3 JavaScript translation to ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I want to translate the following JavaScript into ClojureScript:

```
var myScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([0, 600]);
```

After creating this function you ought to be able to call it with a number:

```
myScale(3);   // returns 180
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
(:require ["d3-scale" :refer (scaleLinear)])

(let [f (-> scaleLinear
            (. (domain (clj->js [0 10])))
            (. (range (clj->js [0 600]))))]
      (f 3))
```

Gives:

> react-dom.development.js:16545 Uncaught TypeError: module$node_modules$d3_scale$dist$d3_scale.scaleLinear.domain is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scaleLinear` is a function that can be called from `d3`. It is not something that ought to be constructed. So this is a better answer:

```
(-> d3
    (.scaleLinear)
    (.domain #js [min-y max-y])
    (.range #js [1 0]))
```

I had trouble with the requires, so here are the relevant ones:

```
["d3" :as d3]
["d3-scale" :refer (scaleLinear)]
```

This is using shadow-cljs rather than cljsjs.

The trouble with requiring "d3" is that you pull the whole library in. So
here's another approach:

```
(-> (scaleLinear)
    (.domain #js [min-y max-y])
    (.range #js [1 0]))
```

It seems that whenever you are requiring something you can use it directly as it was required, and forget the interop dot.

Also `(:require ["d3" :as d3])` means that you pull d3 into the local scope. `js/d3` is the global scope, so just use `d3` if that's what you have required. i.e. `js` is another 'interop' thing you can forget about.

On the other hand `domain` and `range` were not required, so interop rules need to be observed.

In conclusion - the main problem solved is that `scaleLinear` is a function and as such actually needs to be called!

This question was asked at the beginning of an exploration into working with d3 through React Vis - see https://medium.com/@cjmurphy/using-react-vis-from-clojurescript-787d02281f7c

Answer (score 1):

With some trial and error I did get it to work. These are all equivalent:

```
(-> (new scaleLinear)
    (.domain (clj->js [0 10]))
    (.range (clj->js [0 600])))

(-> (new scaleLinear)
    (. (domain (clj->js [0 10])))
    (. (range (clj->js [0 600]))))

(-> (scaleLinear.)
    (.domain #js [0 10])
    (.range #js [0 600]))
```